# Arrow deletes heteroatoms in chemfig

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, chemfig

I neither know nor understand why arrow delete all heteroatoms in a reaction mechanism using `chemfig`.

```
\usepackage{chemfig,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\schemestart
\definesubmol\N{\textcolor{blue}{N}}
\definesubmol\Ox{\textcolor{red}{O}}
\definesubmol\Am{\textcolor{blue}{NH_2}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-@{a3}=@{a1}(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)}}{Timina} \hspace{1.2em} \chemname{\chemfig{*6(@{a4}-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-@{a2}(-)=)}}{Timina} \arrow \chemname{\chemfig{*6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-([:0]-([:30]*6(-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-([:105]-)-)))-([:0]-)([:75]-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)}}{Dímero de timina ciclobutano}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw[red](a1)+(south:0.5cm)..controls+(north east:1cm)and +..(a2);\draw[red](a4)+(north:0.5cm)..controls+(south west:1cm)and+..(a3);}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The desired result is this, but when I compile all heteroatoms are deleted and many errors appeared

[image: Desired result]

[image: Obtained and disappointing result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
        \definesubmol\N{\textcolor{blue}{N}}
        \definesubmol\Ox{\textcolor{red}{O}}
        \definesubmol\Am{\textcolor{blue}{NH_2}}
        \schemestart
        \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-@{a1}=[@{a2}](-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)
        }}{Timina}
        \hspace{1.2em}
        \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6(-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-@{a3}(-)=[@{a4}])
        }}{Timina}
        \arrow
        \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-([:0]-([:30]*6(-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-([:105]-)-)))-([:0]-)([:75]-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)
        }}{Dímero de timina ciclobutano}
        \schemestop
        \chemmove{
            \draw[red] (a2) ..controls +(45:1) and +(180:0.2).. (a3);
            \draw[red] (a4) ..controls +(225:1) and +(0:0.2).. (a1);
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer because is an optimisation, for mechanism red arrow, where can I find how to change coordinates (east,north, west,south) correctly to numbers... but I try to run this in overleaf and the black arrow still deleting all heteroatoms :(

Comment: @DavidTorresV Maybe try recompiling from scratch (that is, deleting the cache before compiling).

Comment: @JasperHabicht It does not work :( Still running without heteroatoms

Comment: @DavidTorresV It is hard to tell where the problem lies. The above code works on Overleaf as well as on a current local LaTeX installation, regardless whether compiled with PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. The output is even correct if I set the TeX Live version on Overleaf to 2014 (Legacy). The same is true for the code posted in the answer of CrocoDuck.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code (the one from the second post) in overleaf and it worked.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \definesubmol\N{\textcolor{blue}{N}}
    \definesubmol\Ox{\textcolor{red}{O}}
    \definesubmol\Am{\textcolor{blue}{NH_2}}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-@{a1}=[@{a2}](-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)
    }}{Timina}
    %
    \hspace{1.2em}
    %
    \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6(-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-@{a3}(-)=[@{a4}])
    }}{Timina}
    %
    \arrow %This arrow is deleting all heteroatoms and groups
    %The problem still running in Overleaf
    \chemname{\chemfig{
            *6((=!\Ox)-!\N(-)-([:0]-([:30]*6(-!\N(-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-(=!\Ox)-([:105]-)-)))-([:0]-)([:75]-)-(=!\Ox)-!\N(-H)-)
    }}{Dímero de timina ciclobutano}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=2pt] (a2) ..controls +(45:1) and +(180:0.2).. (a3);
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=2pt] (a4) ..controls +(225:1) and +(0:0.2).. (a1);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]